# Removal from JSON array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm managing a followers list through a JSON array. I'm using JSON_ARRAY_APPEND to add a follower:

```sql
UPDATE users 
SET follows = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(follows, '$', "followerToBeAdded") 
WHERE username = "user"
```

However, I'm unable to remove a follower from this list. If I try JSON REMOVE, it just erases the whole JSON array instead of just removing a particular follower from the list.

Any idea of a possible query for it?

Comment: Are you using mariaDB or MySQL?

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts and desired final data state for it. Specify precise DBMS version.

Comment: @4EACH MySQL. Harry's query worked perfectly (accepted it as an answer to the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've added the `MySQL` tag in the question so the following response is inaccordance with `MySQL`.

Let's consider the `users` table with the two columns `username` and json column `follows`. Assume we've a username `x` and one follower `a` to begin with.

Let's add 2nd and 3rd follower

```
UPDATE users SET follows = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(follows, '$', 'b') where username ='x';
UPDATE users SET follows = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(follows, '$', 'c') where username ='x';
```

**Removal:** Let's say we want to remove the follower `b`
To check the follower to be removed

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(follows, 'one', 'b')  FROM users;
```

Above will give path to the object to be deleted in the array.

```
UPDATE users SET follows = JSON_REMOVE(follows, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(follows, 'one', 'b'))) WHERE JSON_SEARCH(follows, 'one', 'b') IS NOT NULL;
```